# asp.net redirect to another url if page size is less then 700px

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page e.g. `desktop.aspx?customerID=345` & `mobile.aspx?customerID=345`. Both pages have same functionality. So supposer user goes here `desktop.aspx?customerID=345` and screen size is less then 700px then it should redirect to `mobile.aspx?customerID=345`. Now with `Jquery` I can do this redirect but here I have dynamic query string as well.

Is it possible to detect screen size in code behind of `.aspx` file?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the code behind rather than the client side? You could use JQuery. If you need it to go back to the server you could use AJAX to pass the screen size back to the server

Comment: @Alex Please show me some dummy code where I can parse jquery values to string in code behind file.

Comment: You could set a cookie with the users' resolution and use that in your code behind, no need for AJAX with this (depending on use case). But note that 700px is an arbitrary number to determine a phone. My phone, for example, has way more horizontal pixels than this (2560x1440).

Comment: @JohanB can you show me one?

Comment: Two different pages for mobile and desktop? This is exactly what CSS media queries are meant to solve in a single page for both.

Comment: @spender No my design structure is something old type of things & lot of data is there. Even I have not used css in that page it is purely table structure so not valid point of using media query

Answer (score 0):

To check the screen and browser width you can use javascript match media:

For browser:

```
var isBrowserLessThan700 = (window).matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 700px)').matches;
```

For the screen:

```
var isDeviceLessThan700 = (window).matchMedia('screen and (max-device-width: 700px)').matches;
```

And if result is true:

```
   window.loacation.href= "What-You-Want";
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:-
Create a hidden field variable in the client side.

.ASPX File:-

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdncustomerID" runat="server" />
```

Script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var hdncustomerID = $('hdncustomerID').Val(); //if u use Jquery

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($(window).width() < 700) {
                window.location = mobile.aspx?customerID=123;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Solution 2:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var CustomerID = 1;

        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        strScript.Append("$(document).ready(function () {");
        strScript.Append("if ($(window).width() < 700) {");
        strScript.Append("window.location = mobile.aspx?customerID='");
        strScript.Append(CustomerID);
        strScript.Append("';");
        strScript.Append("}");
        strScript.Append(" });");
        strScript.Append("</script>");

        ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript;
        script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "redirect", strScript.ToString());

    }
```

Hope Its Work !!!

Comment: I need to parse size to code behind & there I need to check. If screen size is <700 then I will redirect it to another page. Here I can't redirect to any other page at client side because links contains querystrings i.e. mobile.aspx?customerID=123 . If I do client side redirection then I can only give mobile.aspx